# convergent or divergent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 9}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got to the point where I get $1/3(\arctan(∞/3)-\arctan(1/3))$ , so since its gonna be a finite number right? Meaning converges

Comment: Use the limit comparison test.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Or the direct comparison test.

Comment: In fact, the value of the sum is $\frac\pi6\coth(3\pi)-\frac1{18}$

Comment: Were you trying to use the integral test for convergence here? If so - there is actually nothing wrong with your solution

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 9}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on the hint given above, we know the following is true: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 9}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

The series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$, is convergent by the p-test (since $p=2\geq1$).

Now because the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2 + 9}$$ converges, by the direct comparison test, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2 + 9}$ converges as well.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$\frac{1}{n^2+9}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Can you continue?